# How to create a Youtube Playlist using Listview in Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, youtube-api

I'm a beginner and student in programming java programming for Android.
I am wanting to create a project in AndroidStudio that from a listing displaying youtube videos from a list of videos of my interest or a playlist.
The project would basically create an APP to access my youtube list in an organized way.

I've tried some features, but no success.
I wanted it to look similar to the APP in the link.

http://www.mediafire.com/view/pj7vjy33rrvv8fm/print.png

Clicking on the listview item this app redirects to a Youtube API.

Could someone help me, please?
Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Here is a start, this will get you to play 1 video, after that you will have to create a ListView with a custom Adapter and then rework your UI to look how you want. [How to Play YouTube Video in Android App](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you can use [this library](https://github.com/prof18/YoutubeParser)
>   very lightweight and easy to implement
>
> you can also check  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491439/youtube-playlist-shown-in-listview?rq=1)